# Conditional ORDER BY based on NULL values in the column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, order-by, null

I have a table like this. 
table(student_name nvarchar(20) not NULL, grades int). 
When I write

```
select * from table
order by grades asc
```

It shows this

```
student_name | grades
---------------------
   Ann       |  NULL
   Bob       |  NULL
   Bob       |   10
   Jane      |   25
   Nelly     |   30
```

when `select * from table
      order by grades desc`

```
   student_name | grades
    ---------------------
      Nelly     |   30
      Jane      |   25
      Bob       |   10
      Ann       |  NULL
      Bob       |  NULL
```

But I need to order by like this. NULLs in the end but those who have grades order by ascending order, like

```
   student_name | grades
    ---------------------
      Bob       |   10
      Jane      |   25
      Nelly     |   30
      Ann       |  NULL
      Bob       |  NULL
```

How it is possible to do a conditional order by like this? How to specify NULL values to be at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You could add a case when check to the order by to give the NULL's a lower priority and then filter on grades**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN grades IS NULL 
THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ASC, grades ASC;
```

**Since you are using integers you can also do this, which should be more performant**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY -grades DESC;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986683/tsql-order-by-with-nulls-first-or-last-at-bottom-or-top/42987693)

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6788209508bd91d6e97c05c70ce3e3f8)

Comment: thanks, but I do not understand how this CASE  gives a priority and how it affects the performance? @RandiVertongen

Comment: @ElGrig no problem, it is simply saying if it is NULL, then put 2 else put 1, after this the second order comes into play, for all the 1's, order on grades asc. Afterwards order on the 2's the remaining grades (all NULL). I added a different possibly more performant approach (also from the source)